# Best way to clean free text then turn into a transaction dataset

Tags: r, text-mining, market-basket-analysis

I have survey information that contains free text that I would like to clean then put into a transaction dataset to run in the arules R package. Right now the text looks like this.

```
id | Answers    
1  | John thinks that the product is not worth the price
2  | Amy believes that the functionality is well above expectations
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
1 | John | thinks   | Product       | Not   | Worth | Price    
1 | Amy  | Believes | Functionality | Above | Expectations
```

Right now I have been able to clean the data using `tm` package but I don't know what is the best way to convert it to a transaction dataset. I've turned the information into all lowercase and removed the stop words.

Let's just say my data is in data frame called "Questions". I am unable to convert the corpus into a transaction dataset after I have cleaned it.

Comment: `stri_split_fixed` of `stringi` library ?

Comment: You should save it as a list not data frame

Comment: Can the contents of my corpus be saved as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(data$Answers, " ")
```

The output is a list:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "John"    "thinks"  "that"    "the"     "product" "is"      "not"     "worth"   "the"     "price"  

[[2]]
[1] "Amy"           "believes"      "that"          "the"           "functionality" "is"           
[7] "well"          "above"         "expectations"
```

## Edit:

Removing duplicates using the `unique` function:

```
my_list <- str_split(data$Answers, " ")
lapply(my_list , unique)

[[1]]
[1] "John"    "thinks"  "that"    "the"     "product" "is"      "not"     "worth"   "price"  

[[2]]
[1] "Amy"           "believes"      "that"          "the"           "functionality" "is"           
[7] "well"          "above"         "expectations"
```

Comment: That did it! Really appreciate the help. You wouldn't happen to know how to keep the uniques from this list? So in each factor only unique words show up. Ex. The product is not like the other product, would be, The product is not like.

Comment: See my edits, and condsider to mark the answer as appropriate by clicking the check button on the left side.

Comment: I must have tried a bunch of different unique function combinations but forgot lapply. Much appreciated again.